# MySQL - if value in column then insert value in another column

Tags: mysql

I want to do bulk update on my database. So I want to know how to insert value to the new column based on the value from other column. E.g.

If value in columnA = 15, then insert 'text' in columnB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not insert, thats update,and you can do it as

```
update table_name
set 
columnB = 
case when columnA = 15 then 'text' end
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer from almost similar question.

```
UPDATE table
SET columnB='text' where (columnA='15')
```

This is much more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET columnB =  IF(columnA = 15, 'text',NULL);
```